# Calling same function from controllers on button click

Tags: angularjs, function

I want to keep save button(common for all the pages)  in index.html. This button is not a part of ng-view.
I have "save" function in all the controller.
When this button is clicked I want to call the "save" function of current controller. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please show some html and controller structure. Question is too vague without seeing some scopes and getting better understanding of issue

Answer (score 0):

You bind your `ng-controller` to the parent element of the button. In controller you assign function to the scope, like so `$scope.myHandler = function() {};` and then on the button you put `ng-click` directive: `ng-click=myHandler()` That's is

Answer (score 0):

You can get the scope of any controller you want.
For Example:

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller="MyController">
</div>
<button onclick="ButtonClick()">
  My Button
</button>

//JavaScript 
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
$scope.clickHandler = function (args) {
    alert(args);
};
});

function ButtonClick(evt){
  angular.element(document.getElementById('myDiv'))
 .scope().clickHandler('test');
}
```